# Pepper robot android emulator is not receiving push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, emulation, pepper

I need to create a fcm push notifications in pepper robot android emulator.
While intializing the fcm notification, i am getting error like Google play services not installed.
It's a standalone android emulator, So i need to make sure whether the pepper robot emulator supports fcm push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Pepper emulator doesn't support Google Play Services and it won't be.

To test FCM push you need to use real Pepper or normal Android Studio Emulator. 
All Pepper apps may be run on the normal android device or emulators.

RobotService not gain focus and Peppers' features don't works, but other "clean android" features works normally.